# passing direct string to a template in c++

Tags: c++, string, templates

C++: passing a string to templates.

Without specifying what type of data type int is working fine, but when we pass a string to a template we are facing error here, could you please help me on this issue.

```
template <Typename T>
T add(T a,T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main() {
    int    res = add(2,5);  // this is execute perfctly.
    string str = add("hello","world"); // here i am getting eror for passing directly string, can we fix this issue without specifying what data type we are passing.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post your entire code including headers and namespace imports (because your code does not currently compile: `string` is defined in a standard-header but this is not shown in your current code).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you think you're passing `std::string` to `add`, but you're not.  You're passing `const char *`.   You cannot call `+` with two character pointers.

If you instead pass two std::strings, then you can call `+` with them.

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename T>
T add(T a,T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

int main() {
    int    res = add(2,5);  // this is execute perfctly.
    std::string str = add("hello"s,"world"s);  // the s on the end makes it a std::string.  

    // this is the same as the line above
    std::string str2 = add(std::string("hello"), std::string("world"));
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/kSqs2l

Comment: If the `using namespace std;` line is not used then the statement `string str = add("hello"s,"world"s);` does not compile. Is there a way to specify the `std::string` specifier `s` without the `using` statement?

Comment: @AmeyaVS  `using namespace std::string_literals;` instead.  https://godbolt.org/z/aaY-rO  This `using` statement is safe to put in real code (unlike using namespace std)  I updated the example using the better practice.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I would have up-voted again for removing the namespace pollution from the code.

Answer (score 0):

To make this clean, and avoid having to specify types at the call site, we first need to disable the template `add` for types that don't support `operator+`, and then provide an overload for those types.

First, disable add for `const char*`...

```
template <typename T>
auto add(T a,T b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Then provide an overload.

The c++17 way:

```
std::string add(std::string_view l, std::string_view r)
{
    auto result = std::string(l);
    result += r;
    return result;
}
```

or c++14 way:

```
std::string add(const char* l, const char* r)
{
    auto result = std::string(l);
    result += r;
    return result;
}
```

Note that while this gets you past your compile error, it is by no means a complete treatment of the problem.

Consider:

```
str = add("hello",6);
```

This will actually return a pointer beyond the end of string referred to by the left hand argument. This is because `(const char* p) + (int n)` results in the address `p + (sizeof(*p) * n)`.

You will need to add some poison in the template declarations to disable this case.

Here's a more complete treatment:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template <typename L, typename R, 
std::enable_if_t
<
    !(   std::is_pointer_v<std::decay_t<L>>
      || std::is_pointer_v<std::decay_t<R>>)

>* = nullptr>
auto add(L a, R b) -> decltype(a + b)
{
    return a + b;
}

std::string add(std::string_view l, std::string_view r)
{
    auto result = std::string(l);
    result += r;
    return result;
}

template<class R>
auto add(std::string_view l, R&& r)
-> decltype(std::to_string(std::forward<R>(r)))
{
    auto result = std::string(l);
    result += std::to_string(std::forward<R>(r));
    return result;
}

template<class L>
auto add(L&& l, std::string_view r)
-> decltype(std::to_string(std::forward<L>(l)))
{
    auto result = std::to_string(std::forward<L>(l));
    result += r;
    return result;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;

    auto emit = [](auto&& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; };

    emit(add(2,5));
    emit(add("hello","world"));
    emit(add("hello"s,"world"));
    emit(add("hello"s,"world"));
    emit(add("hello",6));
    emit(add(6, "hello"));
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
7
helloworld
helloworld
helloworld
hello6
6hello
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3b217ee301b3a74